# Sybase JDBC connection login failed when run as WAR file; but login success when run within Eclipse

Tags: spring, jdbc, sybase, bouncycastle, sap-ase

I am trying to connect to **Sybase database** from a **Spring Boot** application.

I am using **JConnect jconn4 jdbc driver**.

Login password is **encrypted** at Sybase server, so I am using **bouncycastle** cryptography API to encrypt the password.

Below is the **block** of code:

This code uses **plain JDBC** to test the connection, later I am planning to modify this to use Spring's JDBCTemplate.

```
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver");
        logger.info("Loaded Sybase driver successfully.....");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and

```
    String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:<url>:<port>/<databasename>";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("ENCRYPT_PASSWORD", "true");
    props.put("JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS", "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider");
    props.put("user", "username");
    props.put("password", "pwd");
```

and

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

**When Login Success into Sybase Server:**

1. Running the application within Eclipse IDE.

**When Login failed into Sybase Server:**

1. Running the generated **WAR** file within **Windows** command prompt.
2. Running the generated **WAR** file within **Linux** Shell (**Dev/QA Server**).

**What I tried alreday:**

1.Compared the **version** of jar file used by the application at **runtime** for the below jars.Because there are **multiple** versions of same jar file exists in **classpath** (from various dependencies).

`jconn4-7.07.jar` (sybase jdbc driver).

`bcprov-jdk16-1.43.ja`r (bouncycastle crypto API).

I used below code block to find the jar used by the application at **runtime**.

```
Class clazz = null;
try {
    clazz = Class.forName("org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider");
    logger.info("BouncyCastleProvider is ... " + clazz.toString());

    if (clazz != null && clazz.getProtectionDomain() != null
            && clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() != null) {
        URL codeLocation = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        logger.info("BouncyCastleProvider jar is ... " + codeLocation.toString());
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    logger.info(e.getMessage());
}
```

2.Found **4 versions** of bcprov-jdk1x-x.xx.jar file through pom.xml's **Dependency** **Hierarchy** window in eclipse and  *'excluded'* three of those files in pom. This is to avoid **version** **conflict** of jar files.

but it is not working :-(.

Why it is able to connect within Eclispe and not while running as WAR?

Any help/direction would be much useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a **lot of research** and spent almost **10 hrs** of effort, I am able to solve this by adding '**CHARSET**' into connection properties.

```
props.put("CHARSET", "iso_1");
```

Moral of the story: Problems may be bigger but solutions aren't :-).